# MySQL Overload Due To Insert Queries

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I've begun to have some immense server problems lately due to the overload on Insert queries. All of the queries on our server have been optimized throughout time, but the traffic has picked up again and the CPUs are maxing out due to the high amount of INSERT queries.

We run an INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE UPDATE query for every visitor that visits our website to track visitors that are online, as well as users that are online and what page they are on.

I'm not sure what other way to accomplish and don't know what to do in order to reduce the server load.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

My favorite way to handle this is to buffer up visitor data in server memory, and then do bulk inserts every so often.

For example, only write to the database when X amount of visitor-logs have been queued up in memory, where X may be between 10 and 1000 depending upon your application.

Even if the command that you send to the database server still contains 1000 insert commands, there will only be one round trip between your application server and the database server. Thus, you will have removed the overhead of managing many distinct connections.

Furthermore, you might consider a NoSQL hybrid such as elastic search for such data for removing the load for your MySQL Server. It scales extremely well and can be optimized for indexing (inserts), queries, or both.

Comment: Hi there. That is a very interesting technique of doing it. Never thought about it :). Very smart. So you'd simply build up a text file of insert queries, then run it every say 200 queries or so?

Comment: instead of a text file, I'd use a memory cache such as memcachedb. I'd write my objects into that cache using a queue datastructure. I'd also cache the queue size, so that I can ask memcachedb "how big is my queue?". You also have the option of flushing the queue synchronously or async. Every time somebody visits, you can check if the queue is full and flush it to DB. Or, you can have a special "heartbeat.php", and have a cron job access that every 30 seconds to see if it needs flushed. That way you don't slow down any visitors.

Comment: No prob, sounds like this is a good problem to have to solved, as your site is performing well. Have fun!